# How to use a select statement and a variable inside IN operator?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to use a select statement and a variable **$userid** that is set to the ID of the user, inside an IN operator, like this:

```
"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN ((SELECT manager_id FROM managers), $userid)";
```

But it's not working. When I remove the **$userid**, it works but I need to include the user id too. It's mandatory. How do I do this?

I'm a noob. So pardon me.

Thanks!

Comment: `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managers) OR id = $userid)";`

Comment: But it is returning the user Id only, for some reason. :( @MarkBaker

Comment: If it's only returning one record with the user ID, perhaps you need to check the `managers` data, and make sure that `manager_id` values match up with `id` values in `users` because the query works

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: You've been told the answer, check your data. If the data is incorrect, then no answer will give you what you're asking.... show some of the id and manager ids from your tables

Comment: Its is returning the user id only? You mean, it doesnt select on manager_id? In your query you are only selecting ID. Maybe i understood you wrong but this might help: `"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managers) OR id = $userid)";`

Comment: @MarkBaker Don't you think `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managers) OR id = $userid)";` should be `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE (id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managers) OR id = $userid)";`

Answer (score 0):

the answer that @Mark Baker put as a comment is the correct one:

```
"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managers) OR id = $userid)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ID are linked with a foreign key, as it seems rational, you could also use a JOIN to achieve the same result with better performance:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN managers m ON m.manager_id = u.id
WHERE m.manager_id IS NOT NULL OR uid = $userid
```

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managers UNION SELECT $userid )";